# Python 3.x: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a short script that will convert a word or sentence into it's alphabetical value, and then jump forward 5 values, and print the result as a string.
For e.g.

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Should change to...

```
'102 103 104'
```

However, I only get the above error.
The code in question:

```
def enc(input, output, seq, str_int):
     input = input.lower()
     output = []
     for char in input:
         num = ord(char) + 5
         str_int = str(num)
         output.append(str_int)
         output = seq.join(output)
     return output
print(enc("hello", [], ' ', ' '))
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something really obvious. Thanks.

Comment: you are converting `output = seq.join(output)` output to string that is why the problem occurs

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be a list originally, but then changed to a string afterwards, to print.

Comment: it should indented straight with return statement or you could remove `output = seq.join(output)` and type `return seq.join(output)` your problem is due to wrong indentation

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems to work. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because of the line -

```
output = seq.join(output)
```

According to the indentation , this is inside the `for` loop, and hence inside the for loop, you are changing the `output` variable to `str` (string) , after that when you try to do `output.append()` , it errors out. This is the main cause of the issue.

I am guessing you actually only intended to do this outside the loop , after completely creating the `output` list. But you really don't need to set it back , you can simply do -

```
def enc(input, output, seq, str_int):
     input = input.lower()
     for char in input:
         num = ord(char) + 5
         str_int = str(num)
         output.append(str_int)
     return seq.join(output)
```

Demo -

```
>>> def enc(input, output, seq, str_int):
...      input = input.lower()
...      for char in input:
...          num = ord(char) + 5
...          str_int = str(num)
...          output.append(str_int)
...      return seq.join(output)
...
>>> print(enc("hello", [], ' ', ' '))
109 106 113 113 116
```

Comment: I realize my mistake now. Thanks again. :)
I would accept your answer, but the timer is a thing.